# Responsive grid layout with perfectly squared cells

Tags: html, css

I have a `<section>` element which must not be larger than 100vh and no wider than 100vw. Ideally it should follow its parent containers dimensions.

The `<section>` should have a grid layout using css variables; `var(--cols, 56)` and `var(--rows, 32)`

Each cell in the grid must be 1:1 ratio, meaning that the cell width must always === cell height.

The `<section>` element should grow if the viewport (parent element) grows, unless this makes the cells not square. If this is the case, the `<section>` element should be centered.  So if the viewport width becomes larger and viewport height becomes smaller, the `<section>` is centered horizontally. But if the viewport height becomes larger and viewport width becomes smaller, the `<section>` element is centered vertically.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<section #widgets>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let widget of widgetConfig">
    <ng-container [libTileContainer]="widget"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</section>
```

```css
section {
    display: grid;
    gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(
      var(--cols, 56),
      calc(((100vw - (var(--cols, 56) * 5px) - 2rem) / (var(--cols, 56))))
    );
    grid-template-rows: repeat(
      var(--rows, 32), 
      calc(((100vw - (var(--cols, 56) * 5px) - 2rem) / (var(--cols, 56))))
    );
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
```

This respects the cells squareness, but it bleeds out of it's parent.
The calculations will also only respect viewport width and not height.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: not sure if it works with grid cells, but you could try css [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) to make them square

Comment: I've tried setting the aspect-ratio on the parent of the section element. This will fix the section width not overflowing, but since the cols and rows are variables I cannot set it to a fixed ratio.

Comment: Oh, you mean setting aspect-ratio on the cells themselves? Yeah, but the cells are not nescessarily elements. And those who do contain elements often fill up more than 1 column and row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the height and width of grid items you might use a strategy that calculates both the height and width according to how many columns and rows are supposed to be fit inside the available space and then just use the lesser of the two on both the properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min

> The min() CSS function lets you set the smallest (most negative) value
> from a list of comma-separated expressions as the value of a CSS
> property value.

In this demo I slightly refactored some choices:

- I removed the default value for the number of columns to simplify the
  code.. anyway it could defined as an other custom property
- I use the function `min` to determine which one is lower between the
  candidates height and width
- I used `place-content` to center the items by default
- I used `grid-auto-rows` to determine the size of rows because it's not
  important here to tell also how many
- I told the `div` to take the whole width and height of their container

```js
const items = 20;
const cols = 5;
const rows = 4;

initSection(items, cols, rows);

function initSection(items, cols, rows){
  const parent = document.querySelector('section');
  for(i=0;i<items;i++){
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerText = i+1;
    parent.append(item);  
  }
  parent.dataset.col = cols;
  parent.dataset.col = rows;
}
```

```css
:root{
  --cols: 56;
  --rows: 32;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /*just to make sure the content doesn't overflow the viewport*/
}

section::before{
  /*this to show that the same dynamic strategy here worked instead*/
  --cols: attr(data-cols);
  --rows: attr(data-rows);
  
  position: absolute;    
  content: var(--cols) 'x' var(--rows);
  border: dashed 4px gray;
  padding: 0 .2em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  top: .2em;
  left: .4em;
}

section {  
  /*!this didn't work :(*/  
  /*
  --cols: attr(data-cols number, 56);
  --row: attr(data-rows number, 32);
  */
      
  --cols: 5;
  --rows: 4;  
  
  --gap: 5px;
  --col-size: calc(((100vw - (var(--cols) * var(--gap))) / (var(--cols))));  
  --row-size: calc(((100vh - (var(--rows) * var(--gap))) / (var(--rows))));    
  --size: min(var(--col-size), var(--row-size));
  
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
  grid-template-columns: repeat( var(--cols), var(--size));
  /*grid-template-rows: repeat( var(--rows), var(--size));*/
  grid-auto-rows: var(--size);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;      
}

section{
  border: solid red;
}

section div {  
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<section data-cols="5" data-rows="4">    
  <!-- 
    <div>1</div>
    ...
  -->
</section>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I was not aware of the min css function.

Comment: I even tried to encode those cols and rows vars in the section data attributes. I frankly have no idea why it didn't work: `--cols: attr(data-cols, 56);` because otherwise it was perfect. And it was also possible to change those attributes via js and yet have the css strategy in place